# QField is not Syncing back

Tags: qgis, qfield, qfieldsync

QGIS 3.24.2-Tisler, QField 2.0.16 - Arctic Fox, QField Sync 4.0

So I have used QField for some time now and it was working great never had a problem but over the winter I did not touch it. Now nothing seems to sync. I have made sure all the setting have not changed sense last time I used it. I made sure it was a .qgs and not a .qgz

There is no error or anything the syncing run smoothly, but no data is brought over, I checked the .qgs from the device and it has the points I want to bring over it just does not do it. I also tried using QField Cloud and same thing no points are brought over.

Comment: Update, I have gotten the Sync to work with QField Cloud but for some reason the cable connection still does not work. I had to move back a version of QGIS to QGIS-3.22.6. I would love to get the Cable connection working though because some of my projects have custom MBtiles and I have not been able to get those to work on QField Cloud yet. I am still digging and will update if I find a fix in the mean time if anyone has any ideas please let me know

Comment: Another Update. I have been able to get the cable version to work. I had to go back to QGIS version "3.20.3". I don't know why it work but I tried using the cable as I normally would and the data came over no problem. If someone could help out on the newest version though that would be awesome because I would rather have one version of QGIS on my computer then two.

Comment: I think I have the same problem. Haven't tested it with an older QGIS version yet. Did you find any new information on that topic?

Answer (score 1):

For cable connection...If you copied to the project into the root folder, or 'Documents' or any other location than 'Android\data\ch.opengis.qfield\files...' on your device, you can't open it directly in QField; you first have to Import Project, navigate to that location and grant access. Annoyingly, it then copies the project to 'Android\data\ch.opengis.qfield\files\Imported Projects' and this is the copy that gets updated. A copy of the project also stays in the original location, but doesn't get edited. You can also only access 'Android\data\ch.opengis.qfield\files' over a cable connection, and not directly from the device). So, for cable connection, place your project files in 'Android\data\ch.opengis.qfield\files\Imported Projects'. That way, no duplicated folders and no confusion about which version has been edited.

Comment: Thank for the help, I normally copy it all off the phone anyway and bring it back to my PC and then extract the information. Then repackage the project once the data has been brought over and use that new package on the phone ( removing the old one from my phone, and storing a backup if needed). It dose not seem the be anything with the folders on the phone it self. Thank again

Comment: I don't understand if the issue is resolved or not. Yes, if you're not using QFieldCloud, you do need to copy files from the phone back to your PC, but you have to use the right files from your phone - that is what my comment was directing you to. If it's resolved, can you vote up my answer accordingly. If not, please explain more.

Comment: No it did not provide a solution as I had already been doing that. If you read my second update you will see that I had to go back to QGIS version "3.20.3" for the operation to work. This means at the moment  I am using two versions of QGIS. Also this is my first post so I can not upvote yet only mark things as answered.